# ffmpegを使用して動画に斜線を描画したい

Tags: ffmpeg

動画内に斜線を描画したく思っております。
縦、横の線でしたら

```
-i input -vf drawbox=10:10:1:200:color='#ff0000':8:enable='between(t,3,5) output
```

のようにdrawboxで引くことは出来ましたが、斜線のやり方がわかりません。
こちらどの様にしたら斜線が引けるのでしょうか

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: [あわせて読みたい類似質問](https://qiita.com/fuzigiwa2/questions/51131e932909ec5cc696)

Answer (score 1):

[ffmpeg draw a line from point to pointの回答](https://superuser.com/a/1142528)によると、下記引用のようにgeqフィルタでif文を使って「X座標とY座標が一致する座標に点を描画する」処理を繰り返して線を描画できるようです。

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex 
      "color=red:s=490x490,geq=lum='p(X,Y))':a='if(eq(X,Y),255,0)'[c];
       [0][c]overlay=10:10:shortest=1" 
out.mp4
```

ただし上記回答のコメントにある通り、この処理はgeqフィルタで画面全体を走査して点描を行うのでコストが大きいです。
[数式で線や円、模様が描ける GEQ](https://nico-lab.net/geq_with_ffmpeg/#i-2)の「負荷を軽くするには」のアドバイス(下記引用)も参考になりそうです。

> geqフィルタは処理が重たいので映像に変化がないならtrimフィルタで1フレームだけ取り出してloopフィルタで繰り返した方がよい。

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i color,geq='st(0,between(X,W/3,2*W/3)*between(Y,H/3,2*H/3));ld(0)*255:128:128',trim=end_frame=1,loop=-1:1:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB
```

Comment: こちら描画する線の太さを変更したい場合はどうすればよいでしょうか。
また、線を複数本描画する場合は
`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex 
      "color=red:s=490x490,geq=lum='p(X,Y))':a='if(eq(X,Y),255,0)'[c];
       [0][c]overlay=10:10:shortest=1" ,
      "color=red:s=390x390,geq=lum='p(X,Y))':a='if(eq(X,Y),255,0)'[c];
       [0][c]overlay=100:100:shortest=1" ,
out.mp4`
のように`,`で区切れば対応できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

代替案として、斜線を引いた画像を用意して動画に合成するという方法も考えられます。

参考:
[FFmpegで動画と画像をブレンド合成して透過する](https://askthewind.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/12/22/140629)